# Find all entities without a relation

Tags: doctrine-orm

My question heavily depends on this: [Doctrine: Query only where relationship doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030480/doctrine-query-only-where-relationship-doesnt-exist)

I wonder how the very same thing can be accomplished using Doctrine2. I am especially interested in good practices. Do I have to use the `QueryBuilder` or is it possible to use a `findBy` on a repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I used `QueryBuilder` like this (example from the question linked above):

```php
// $entitiyManager: Doctrine EntityManager instance
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$x = $qb->expr();

$qb->select('article')
    ->from('Article', 'article')
    ->leftJoin('article.category', 'category')
    ->where($x->isNotNull('category.id');
```